# I got some problems while importing C++ dynamic library into Python

Tags: python, c++, dll

I created an example of a dynamic library in C++

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {

    void TaylorSeries(int x1, int x2, int delta_x, double E) {

        std::cout << x1 << x2 << std::endl;

    }

}
```

create from this .cpp file dinamic library using commands "g++ -shared -fPIC -o lib.so lib.cpp" and "g++ -shared -o lib.dll lib.cpp" and then import to Python file

```
from ctypes import cdll

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./lib.so') 

lib.TaylorSeries(1, 3, 1, 1.0)
```

i got an error:

> lib.TaylorSeries(1, 3, 1, 1.0) # Call the hello function from the library ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: TypeError: Don't know how to convert parameter 4

I don't know how to solve it because I'm working with dynamic libraries for the first time

I have no idea how to make python understand the double type from C++

Comment: `lib.TaylorSeries(1, 3, 1, c_double(1.0))` (importing of `c_double` from ctypes needed).

Comment: Looks the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75849584/4788546.